# How to trap Java windowIconified() and windowIDeconified() before updateUiChanged() event?

Tags: java, swing

My Java Swing application uses updateUiChanged() to resize fonts after its jFrame has been resized by the user. But updateUiChanged() is getting triggered when the jFrame is minimized and then maximized which is causing problem

I tried to trap the minimize and maximize events with the following, but they do not execute at all or they execute after the updateUiChanged() which is too late.

How can I trap the minimize and maximize before the updateUiChanged()
See below for the updateUiChanged implementation.
Thanks

```
   private WindowListener wndMinMax;    

   wndMinMax = new WindowAdapter(){

        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
            if(debug)debug("Window Iconfied!!");
            return;
        }
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){
            if(debug)debug("Window DeIconfied!!");
            return;
        }

    };
    this.addWindowListener(wndMinMax); 


    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()                     
    {                                                               
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) //V.43
        {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JFrame) //V.43
            {
                updateUiChanged((int) e.getComponent().getWidth(),
                        (int) e.getComponent().getHeight());        
            }
        }                                                           
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to just listen for changes to the window’s size using a ComponentListener?

Comment: I am using a component listener to trap the resize (see below). 
The problem is that is executes before the iconfiy and deiconify events. I don't know how to test for iconfiy or deiconify inside of the  componentListener. 
Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to make sure your updateUiChanged call takes place after the WindowEvent.  You can track the occurrence of a WindowEvent in a private instance field, so your delayed ComponentListener code can know if the resize was paired with a WindowEvent:

```
private boolean iconifyStateChanged;

// ...

wndMinMax = new WindowAdapter(){

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
        if(debug)debug("Window Iconfied!!");
        iconifyStateChanged = true;
    }
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){
        if(debug)debug("Window DeIconfied!!");
        iconifyStateChanged = true;
    }
};
this.addWindowListener(wndMinMax); 

addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()                     
{                                                               
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) //V.43
    {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JFrame) //V.43
        {
            // This will run after any pending WindowEvents.
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                if (!iconifyStateChanged)
                {
                    updateUiChanged(e.getComponent().getWidth(),
                                    e.getComponent().getHeight()));
                }
                iconifyStateChanged = false;
            });
        }
    }                                                           
});
```

([getWidth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getWidth()) and [getHeight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getHeight()) already return int values, so a cast to int is not necessary.)